# Game scene not garbage collecting

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my android game I have entire game scenes/ levels wrapped in a GameScene object. I was hoping that the GameScene object would garbage collect once the reference was replaced by new GameScene. Unfortunately I have bad memory leaks, where everytime change the level, the memory heap grows. This happens until the game crashes with memory full errors. I already used eclipse Mat and it warned me that there was a likely leak in GameScene. I fixed it so it doesn't show up on Mat anymore. Does anyone who is good at debugging in eclipse know how I can figure out which objects are not being garbage collected? I'm not even sure if GameScene is being garbage collected. The code below just gives a shorted example of how I am calling Engine to create and overwrite the current GameScene inside of the running GameScene to create the next level.

```
class GameScene{
//lots of methods and objects...
@Override
  public void onClick(float x, float y) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Engine.destroyScene();
  Engine.setScene(new GameScene(context, "chapters/classic/2/"));
 }
}
class SceneManager{
 public Scene currentScene;

 public void destroyScene() {
        sceneLoaded = false;
        currentScene.destroyScene();
        currentScene = null;
    }

    public void setScene(Scene scene) {
        currentScene = scene;
    }

    public void loadScene() {
        currentScene.loadScene();
        sceneLoaded = true;
    }
}

class Engine{
  public static void destroyScene(){
    sceneManager.destroyScene();
    resourceManager.deleteAllTextures();
  }

    public static void setScene(Scene scene) {
        sceneManager.setScene(scene);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is unfortunately nothing in the code you posted that shows a leak. `currentScene = null;` does work. There must be something else leaking.

Comment: post the `Scene#destroyScene` code.

Comment: I only have jni calls in destroyScene. I fixed half of this by adding static in front of the objects in GameScene.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a profiler like VisualVm (included in the JDK) to see the status of your memory, the number of instances of each objects and other usefull information.

In your case, I'd take a snapshot of the memory in the beginning, then go through game scenes and take another snapshot to compare with the first one. Another option VisualVM offers is to make a heapdump when an OutOfMemoryException occurs, which you can then go through to find the source of the problem.